# Get one row in table1 and Two or more rows in table2 in one array

Tags: mysql, sql

Im newbie here. Suppose 2 tables in database:

Table 1: tournaments

```
+------------+----------+---------+----------+
|    id      |  format  |  Size   |  host    |
+------------+----------+---------+----------+
|     7      |  Single  |   9     |  Daniel  |
|     8      |  Single  |   4     |  Oscar   |
+------------+----------+---------+----------+
```

Table 2: matchs

```
+------------+----------+-------------+----------+----------+
|    id      |  player  |  position   |  score   |  winner  |
+------------+----------+-------------+----------+----------+
|     7      |  Arturo  |     0       |    3     |    1     |
|     7      |  Pablo   |     1       |    2     |    0     |
|     8      |  Ale     |     0       |    1     |    0     |
|     8      |  Maria   |     1       |    5     |    1     |
+------------+----------+-------------+----------+----------+
```

Now i want to get the host, size, winner, player, Score where ID is 7 and 8. Do you know how iget the following structure?:

```
[ Host:Daniel, size: 9, [ winner:1, player: Arturo, Score: 3], [winner:0, player: Pablo, Score: 2]], [host:Óscar, size:4,[winner:0, player: Ale, Score:0],....
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please, format your tables structure  so to it would result in a question that is clear and answerable.

Answer (score 0):

Use [JOIN Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) to join the tables by `id` field:

```
SELECT
  host, size, winner, player, score
FROM 
  tournaments INNER JOIN matchs USING (id);
```

If you want to select rows that contains specific `id`only,  then use `WHERE`  clause. In your case append following to the query before semicolon:

```
WHERE `id` IN (7, 8)
```

Note, the MySQL can not create complex objects. [SELECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) returns set of rows only. To convert returned data set to structure, use external tools of your server side platform: C,  C++, C#, VB.NET, Python, PHP, etc.